# Can't Navigate To Custom Screen - React Navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I want to navigate from Order screen To Home Screen but he doesn't work very well, every screen in the route is work, But Home screen Nope, Just back me to the Map screen, And I want Home Screen Not Map !! I already tell them to navigate to **Home.**

Here is structure I'm Dowing

> Home -> Map -> Order, then Order -> Home

and in the Home, I have side menu Drawer check under the code.

**Route.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

//Import required react-navigation component 
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
  createSwitchNavigator
} from 'react-navigation';

//Import all the screens for Drawer/ Sidebar
import Home from "../screens/Home";
import Splash from "../screens/Splash";
import SignUp from "../screens/SignUp";
import SignIn from "../screens/SignIn";
import ForgetPassword from "../screens/ForgetPassword";
import Order from "../screens/Order";
import MapApp from "../screens/MapApp";
import Profile from "../screens/Profile";


import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

//Navigation Drawer Structure for all screen
class NavigationDrawerStructure extends Component {
  //Structure for the navigatin Drawer
  toggleDrawer = () => {
    //Props to open/close the drawer
    this.props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}>
          <Icon name="md-menu" size={30} color='#fff' style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

// Stack Navigator for app
const AuthStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  //All the screen from the Screen1 will be indexed here
  SignUp: {
    screen: SignUp,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      // header: null
      title: "Sign Up",
      headerLeft: null,
      headerTintColor: "#0496FF",
      headerStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: "white"
      },
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#0496FF",
        textAlign: "center",
        flex: 1,
        elevation: 0,
        fontSize: 25,
        justifyContent: "center"
      }
    })
  },
  SignIn: {
    screen: SignIn,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Sign In",
      headerRight: <View />,
      headerTintColor: "#0496FF",
      headerStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: "white"
      },
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#0496FF",
        textAlign: "center",
        flex: 1,
        elevation: 0,
        fontSize: 25,
        justifyContent: "center"
      }
    }
  },
  ForgetPassword: {
    screen: ForgetPassword,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Forget Password",
      headerRight: <View />,
      headerTintColor: "#0496FF",
      headerStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: "white"
      },
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#0496FF",
        textAlign: "center",
        flex: 1,
        elevation: 0,
        fontSize: 25,
        justifyContent: "center"
      }
    }
  },

});

//Stack Navigator for First Option of Navigation Drawer
const HomeDrawer = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Home',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
      headerRight: <View />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#258fdb',
        shadowOpacity: 0,
        elevation: 0,
        marginBottom: 20
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        textAlign: "center",
        flex: 1,
        elevation: 0,
        fontSize: 25,
        justifyContent: "center"
      }
    }),
  },
  MapApp: {
    screen: MapApp,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Map",
      headerRight: <View />,
      headerLeft: <View />,
      headerTintColor: "#fff",
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#258fdb",
        borderBottomColor: "white",
      },
      headerTitleStyle: {
        textAlign: "center",
        flex: 1,
        elevation: 0,
        fontSize: 25,
        justifyContent: "center"
      }
    }
  }
});

//Stack Navigator for Second Option of Navigation Drawer
const OrderDrawer = createStackNavigator({
  Order: {
    screen: Order,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Order',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#258fdb',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});
const ProfileDrawer = createStackNavigator({
  Profile: {
    screen: Profile,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Profile',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,

      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#258fdb',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
})
//Drawer Navigator for the Navigation Drawer / Sidebar
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeDrawer,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Home',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Icon name="ios-home" size={30} color='#0496FF' />
      ),
    },

  },
  Order: {
    screen: OrderDrawer,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Order',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Icon name="ios-list-box" size={30} color='#0496FF' />
      ),
    },
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: ProfileDrawer,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Profile',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Icon name="ios-contact" size={30} color='#0496FF' />
      ),
    },
  },
});

const Navigations = createSwitchNavigator({
  Authloading: Splash,
  Auth: AuthStackNavigator, // the Auth stack
  App: DrawerNavigator, // the App stack
})

export default MyApp = createAppContainer(Navigations);
```

**Order.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from "../Style/styles";
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
import ImagePicker from "react-native-image-picker";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, ScrollView, KeyboardAvoidingView, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';

// create a component

class Order extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userId: null,
            nameOfProblem: '',
            description: '',
            imageOfPrblem: '',
            timeDate: {},
            providerId: this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().getParam('providerId'),
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        this.setState({ userId });
    }
    handleOrder = () => {
        const { nameOfProblem, description, userId, imageOfPrblem, providerId } = this.state;
        const PushData = firebase.database().ref("request/" + providerId + "/" + userId + "/orders/");
        const ref = firebase.storage().ref("users/" + userId + "/UserImageOrders/" + path);
        let file = imageOfPrblem.uri;
        const path = "img_" + imageOfPrblem.fileName;
        if (file) {
            return (
                PushData.update({
                    nameOfProblem: nameOfProblem,
                    description: description,
                    // ...this.state.nameOfProblem,
                    // ...this.state.description,
                    imageOfPrblem: imageOfPrblem
                }).then(() => {
                    ref.put(file).then(() => {
                        console.log("File uploaded..")
                        setTimeout(() => {
this.props.navigation.navigate("Home"); // not working and get me back to Map screen, but when i navigate to other screen it's work fine!
                        }, 3000);
                    });
                })
            )
        }
        else {
            return (
                PushData.push({
                    nameOfProblem: nameOfProblem,
                    description: description,
                }).then(() => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.props.navigation.navigate("Home"); // Not work
                    }, 3000);
                })
            )
        }
        // else {

        // }
    }

    handleImages = () => {
        const options = {
            title: "Select Images!",
            storageOptions: {
                skipBackup: true,
                path: "images"
            }
        };
        ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
            console.log("Response = ", response);
            if (response.uri) {
                this.setState({ imageOfPrblem: response });
            }
            if (response.didCancel) {
                console.log("User cancelled image picker");
            } else if (response.error) {
                console.log("ImagePicker Error: ", response.error);
            } else if (response.customButton) {
                console.log("User tapped custom button: ", response.customButton);
                alert(response.customButton);
            }
        });
    };

    render() {
        const { nameOfProblem, description, imageOfPrblem, timeDate } = this.state;
        const { getParam } = this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent();
        const providerId = getParam('providerId');
        const providerName = getParam('providerName');
        return (
            <ScrollView scrollEnabled={true}>
                <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" keyboardVerticalOffset={70}>
                    <View style={[styles.container, { marginTop: 20 }]}>
                        <Text>Send Order To: {JSON.stringify(providerName)}, ID:{JSON.stringify(providerId)}</Text>

                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.textInput}
                            placeholder="Name of Problem"
                            value={nameOfProblem}
                            onChangeText={(nameOfProblem) => this.setState({ nameOfProblem })}
                            returnKeyType="next"
                            returnKeyLabel="next"
                        />

                        <TextInput
                            style={[styles.textInput, {
                                borderRadius: 5,
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                height: 120,
                                fontSize: 16,
                                padding: 10,
                                marginTop: 8
                            }]}
                            placeholder="Description"
                            multiline={true}
                            numberOfLines={12}
                            textAlignVertical="top"
                            value={description}
                            onChangeText={(description) => this.setState({ description })}
                            returnKeyType="next"
                            returnKeyLabel="next"
                        />

                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleImages}>
                            <View
                                style={{
                                    backgroundColor: "#DBDBDB",
                                    borderRadius: 100,
                                    alignSelf: "center",
                                    margin: 10,
                                    paddingBottom: 2,
                                    width: 120,
                                    height: 120
                                }}
                            >
                                <Text
                                    style={{
                                        position: "absolute",
                                        zIndex: 1,
                                        fontSize: 40,
                                        top: 67,
                                        color: "#1567d3",
                                        left: 99
                                    }}
                                >
                                    +
                                </Text>
                                <Image
                                    source={{ uri: imageOfPrblem.uri }}
                                    style={[styles.uploadAvatar, { borderRadius: 100 }]}
                                    resizeMode="cover"
                                />

                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={[styles.button, { backgroundColor: "#1567d3" }]}
                            onPress={this.handleOrder}
                        >
                            <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 18 }}>Send</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }

}

// define your styles

//make this component available to the app
export default Order;
```

Comment: your code seems to work https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/graceful-ramen

Comment: In your Snack, it's work very well, But in my app doesn't work, when I'm in order screen then open the Drawer and click to Home screen this move me to Map screen instead Home!

Comment: and when I sent order assumed move me to Home screen it takes me to Map again

Comment: I think it's hard for us to debug, when we don't have fully functioning `Order` component. I tried using your couldn't get it to work on the snack.

Comment: @JuniusL. you haven't taken the Map screen into account, if you add a button in MapApp to move to the Order screen and a button in Order to move to the Home screen, you'll see the issue.

Comment: *and a button in Home to move to the Map screen

Answer (score 0):

You have two routes with the name "Home", one in `HomeDrawer` and one in `DrawerNavigator`. Rename the one in `DrawerNavigator` and it should navigate to the correct "Home".

For example:

```js
HomeDrawer: { // renamed this from Home to HomeDrawer
    screen: HomeDrawer,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Home',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Icon name="ios-home" size={30} color='#0496FF' />
      ),
    },

  },
```

Comment: sadly Not Working!

Comment: @DevAS did you rename the key or the `drawerLabel`? I've updated my answer to show what you should rename.

Comment: @zaytrix OH Yes, it's work like a charm, I have one last question, If I need to clear the parameters I passed in the map screen to order, I'm really doing that in **Order Screen** componentWillUnmount but it's not invoked

Comment: the issue is when the user sends the order and go to the Home screen and select some categories he will send new order with different param I passed not the previous param like "Id-name"

Comment: @DevAS try using the navigation lifecycle rather than the component lifecycle: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle Using `willBlur` or `didBlur`.

Comment: I'm already thinking about this but how to update the new param if I want to using willBlur or didblur based on the new params in the home screen!

Comment: here are the scenarios, the user opens the Home screen and selects any category then open to hem the map screen to select one provider when he selects one of them I'm passing id and name to the order screen now he will send the order and get back to Home screen to return the cycle but now when he selects the other provider they will not update the new id and name I passes just take the previous Id and that's my issue.

Comment: @DevAS Sorry I'm not entirely sure how to help with that issue, you should create a new question so that others may be able to help

Answer (score 0):

When exporting Home.js, export it like this (using withNavigation ).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> Home </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default withNavigation(Home);
```

Comment: Why to do that?